# Related to Modal Popup in jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using modal popup in my project and its working perfectly, I used it in two buttons Edit and Delete, but the problem is when I edit I want to maintain its height according to the project but in case of delete I have to maintain in some other case, so what should I need to do so that I can use one modal but with different functionality.

here, is my modal popup code

```
<div class="modal inmodal" id="dynamicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content animated flipInY">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div id="">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeModal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="jq-server-response">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-primary-btn jq-modal-primary-btn pull-right margin-left-5">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white modal-close-btn pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <div class="pull-right jq-modal-form-loader hide">
                    <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-wave">
                        <div class="sk-rect1"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect2"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect3"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect4"></div>
                        <div class="sk-rect5"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dynamic-modal-spinner hide">
    <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-wave">
        <div class="sk-rect1"></div>
        <div class="sk-rect2"></div>
        <div class="sk-rect3"></div>
        <div class="sk-rect4"></div>
        <div class="sk-rect5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I give height to modal - body like this

```
.modal-dialog {
    overflow-y: initial !important
}

.modal-body {
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

At the time of Edit it open in the way I[image] want like

But, in case of delete, I want less height

here is my javascript code ...

```
$(function () {
    $('.searchclick').click(function () {

        $('.jq-billing-meter').removeClass('search-meter');

        $(this).parents('.form-group').find('.jq-billing-meter').addClass('search-meter')
        //$('.searchclick').parentsUntil('.formgroup');
        //$(this).children('input').addClass('activetext');
    })

    $('body').delegate('.open-dynamic-modal-link', 'click', function (ev) {
        var $this = $(this);
        modal($this);

    });


    //click event on modal primary btn
    $('body').delegate('.jq-modal-primary-btn', 'click', function (ev) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');

        $form.submit();
    });


});

function modal($this) {
    var $spinner = $('.dynamic-modal-spinner');

    // $("h2").siblings("p").css({ "color": "red", "border": "2px solid red" });

    var dataUrl = $this.data('url');
    var dataClose = $this.data('close');
    var dataPrimary = $this.data('primary');
    var dataTitle = $this.data('title');
    var onLoadCallback = $this.data('onload');

    var hasDataUrl = dataUrl != undefined && typeof dataUrl != "undefined" && dataUrl != '';
    var url = hasDataUrl ? dataUrl : $this.attr('href');

    if (hasDataUrl == false) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    var isLargeModal = $this.data('large');
    var isMiniModal = $this.data('mini');

    if (isLargeModal) {
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-dialog').addClass('modal-lg');
    } else {
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-lg');
    }

    if (isMiniModal) {
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-dialog').addClass('modal-sm');
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-title').addClass('modal-small-title');
    } else {
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-sm');
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-title').removeClass('modal-small-title');
    }

    // $('#dynamicModal .modal-title').text(title);

    $('#dynamicModal .modal-title').html(dataTitle);

    $('#dynamicModal .modal-body').html($spinner.html());

    if (dataPrimary) {
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-primary-btn').text(dataPrimary)
    } else {
        $('#dynamicModal .modal-primary-btn').addClass('hide')
    }

    if (dataClose) {

        $('#dynamicModal .modal-close-btn').text(dataClose)

    } else {

        $('#dynamicModal .modal-close-btn').addClass('hide')

    }



    $('#dynamicModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false },'show');



    $('#dynamicModal .modal-body').load(url, function () {
        // Now that the DOM is updated let's refresh the unobtrusive validation rules on the form:
        $('#dynamicModal form').removeData('validator')
            .removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');

        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#dynamicModal form');
        //crystalPower.initDatePicker();
        if (typeof window[onLoadCallback] == "function") { //if onLoadCallback is a valid function
            window[onLoadCallback](); //call function
            //} else if (typeof crystalPower[onLoadCallback] == "function") { //if onLoadCallback is a valid function
            //    crystalPower[onLoadCallback](); //call function
        }

        //if page has autoCompleteInit function available
        if (typeof window["autoCompleteInit"] == "function") {
            window["autoCompleteInit"]();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the javascript code that opens the modal? That's where you set the height

Comment: Oh i forgot to provide here

Comment: Hi,i added please check once

Comment: And is this the modal library that you are using? http://jquerymodal.com/ I have used the jqueryui modal a little bit but I'm not familiar with the library that you are using.